# Запись из БД в массив и вывод в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть БД с таблицей и записями в ней. Необходимо записать данные из БД в массив и вывести их в виде таблицы.

Кусок кода, где представлена запись в массив

```
  <?php
      mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db("bospor_abons") or die(mysql_error());
      $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM abons_table";
      $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
      $abons = array();
      while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $abons[] = array_values($rows);
      }
      var_dump($abons);
      mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Получается вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять почему все данные дублируются. И как это все нормально вывести в таблицу, чтобы все поля одного столбца БД выводились в одну строку? Насколько понимаю нужно использовать цикл foreach, но как именно - понять не могу. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно, как вариант, печатать сразу из `while()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значения дублируются, так как вы используете для выборки mysql_fetch_array, у которого вторым параметром является $result_type и по умолчанию равен MYSQL_BOTH. Это значит, что он вернет значения как для ассоциативных, так и для числовых индексов.

Вы можете использовать вместо этого:

`mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

или для числовых индексов

`mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_NUM)`

Так же вы можете вместо этого соответственно использовать:

`mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)`

или

`mysql_fetch_row($rs)`

Однако, я вам **настоятельно рекомендую** перестать использовать deprecated методы и посмотреть на [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. На счет PDO учту.

Answer (score 2):

Код ниже делает не так - *чтобы все поля одного столбца БД выводились в одну строку*.  Он выводит в строку таблицы одну запись из БД

```
echo '<table>';
forech ($abons as $row)
   echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $row) . '</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: да тут ничего сложного. удачи!